How to make take-vector-screenshot work with PyCharm (under Ubuntu 22.04)?
My goal is to take vector screenshots of my Python development IDE.
I am using PyCharm community edition under Ubuntu 22.04.
I have the package gtk-vector-screenshot installed (see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+package/gtk-vector-screenshot), which theoretically should do the trick.
It allows me to take pdf screenshots of, e.g., Eclipse or LibreOffice.
However, it does not work with PyCharm.
If I start take-vector-screenshot, click the button, then click into the PyCharm window, nothing happens (as opposed to the screenshot being taken).
Now LibreOffice, Eclipse, and PyCharm are all Java applications (at least, as far as I can see).
So I wonder whether there is any configuration setting or anything else that I could do to get take-vector-screenshot to work with PyCharm?
Maybe PyCharm, for some reason, is not using the "right" GTK version and I could force it to do so?
Alternative methods to take vector screenshots of PyCharm would be welcome answers too.
The question is not about "normal" screenshots (raster graphic/bitmap formats, like png or jpg), though.
I want to take screenshots of the whole IDE, i.e., the menu, windows, tool bar, etc.
So screenshots of only the code itself would not solve my problem.
I would be thankful for any ideas and suggestions.
Thomas.

LibreOffice is predominantly not Java.  Eclipse uses SWT, which has some special GTK bindings.  I tested a simple "Hello World" example with a small test Java application and despite setting UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); and confirming that it's using the GTK theme, the screenshot won't work.

... I continued testing, forcing -Djdk.gtk.version=3, which certainly changes the look and feel of the "Hello World" application slightly, but the vector screenshot still does not work.  If vector screenshots of Java are possible, I believe the above to be a requirement, which may be hard to do with a heavily themed application such as PyCharm, IntelliJ, etc.   I was hoping to provide a solution, but -- at time of writing this -- it appears the take-vector-screenshot isn't yet compatible with (most) Java applications.  All tests were done using Xorg.  Wayland crashed.

... I tested both light mode and dark mode to no avail.  "Hello World" source code available here.

As a stop-gap solution, the plugin "Easy Code Screenshots" can take high quality screenshots of code, but is NOT vector and does not include the rest of the IDE.

As said, on my Ubuntu Linux 22.04, I can take vector screenshots of LibreOffice and of Eclipse. Both work just fine. I assume that swing or something use GTK as backend here... ...which is why I wondered why it does not work with PyCharm.

"Easy Code Screenshots" is unfortunately the complete opposite of what I need. I can include code in my documents as nicely formatted listings already, what I need is the screenshot of the IDE, with all the buttons and stuff, and that should be in a vector format...

"I assume that swing or something use GTK as backend here".   I've explained that they don't use swing and provided proof that a swing app -- even when leveraging the Gtk3 theme -- won't work.  LibreOffice doesn't really use Java.  Eclipse uses a special SWT framework, which is not Swing.  Even if Swing worked, IntelliJ uses its own custom theme which I don't believe leverages any of the Gtk3 theme bindings.  Sadly, I don't think this is possible with the tools available currently.  Swing does have a way to print the UI, but the IDE seems to lack this feature.

Yes, I do understand that you said that. However, I can take vector screenshots of Eclipse and LibreOffice on my machine.

The fact that this has been repeated three times now suggests that perhaps there still may be a misunderstanding as neither of those applications use similar Java rendering techniques as PyCharm.  Put simply, if you can't get a basic Java app working, you'll never get PyCharm working.  Eclipse is not a basic Java app as it uses non-standard windowing techniques from SWT, which require GTK bindings: https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#gtkstartup

All of this is well said. However, this is not necessarily the problem. As you point out yourself, neither Eclipse nor LibreOffice seem to use purely Java-based rendering or something. However, for the fourth time, I can screenshot both applications just fine. So they probably use GTK. Now if PyCharm also uses GTK - which I am not sure of - I may have a shot here. If I point the screenshot tool at something that does not use GTK, I get an error message. For PyCharm, I get nothing. So I think that there may be some sort of configuration key that helps, unless it is a code-based issue.
